# Is there script for svn diff/patch with full history and property modification support?

Tags: git, svn, webkit

I tried to use svn apply from 1.7.0, but it doesn't satisfy me. I noticed that history doesn't saved for simple svn mv of a file.

I found svn-apply and svn-create-patch in WebKit project, but they don't support, for example, handle copied directories.

Is there script for svn diff/patch with full history and property modification support?

Git diff/apply is wonderful. Can we somehow use git diff/apply over svn working copy?